# How do I prep for tilling over my yard

Tags: lawn, tilling

I'm not a gardener by any stretch so I need some advice and a game plan for a very simple project I have.

I have a small front yard (about 70sq ft or so) that recently got partially dug up to repair a sewer line. The yard was never in the best shape so I'd like to just till the whole thing over and start fresh.

My problem is the whole area of the trench is hard clay with a large number of small to medium sized rocks.

My plan right now is:

1. Remove as many of the rocks as I can.
2. Remove any weeds
3. Rent a tiller and till the whole yard
4. Lay down fresh topsoil
5. Tamp down the topsoil
6. Plant fresh grass

The problem is I'm not sure what kind of tiller I should rent or what kind of small rocks a tiller can handle.

Any advice on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I can post photos if that would be helpful

Comment: Welcome! You've given a lot of detail, but pictures are always helpful and appreciated. Thanks!